# Need a script that will stream the newest MySQL field entrys

Tags: php, mysql, html, stream, streaming

I want a PHP script to stream all new entries to a MySQL field. So lets say there are 10 of the newest displaying on a page, in time order because the field has a datetime. If anyone can help it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    // connect to the database at 127.0.0.1 (localhost) 
    // with username mysql_username and password mysql_password
    $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'mysql_username', 'mysql_password');

    // fire off query
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT fieldname FROM tablename ORDER BY datefield DESC LIMIT 10", $link);


    // loop through results, displaying field.
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['fieldname'];
    }

    // close the connection to the database
    mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

The SQL you'll need will be along the lines of the following

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY datetimeField DESC LIMIT 10
```

Then you just iterate over the result of your query in your PHP.